# display an SSRS report on an ASPNET WebForm page created with VisualStudio2017

Tags: reporting-services, webforms, visual-studio-2017

[SOLVED] I created a BI project report, and I exported it on SSRS installed local,
the report works if displayed on the SSRS webapp Manager

http://localhost/Reports/Reports/ProgettoReport1/ReportVendutoProdotti1

I'm trying to display the report on an ASPNET WebForm page,
but I'm having trouble

my steps:

- via NuGet I installed the UserControl Microsoft.Report.Viewer v 11.0.0
- I created a WebForm .aspx page and I added the UserControl Report.Viewer, and I configured 
  it on the same page

/////////////////////////////////////

page code  ReportVendutoProdotti.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ReportVendutoProdotti.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_ReportVendutoProdotti" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            ReportViewer1
        </div>
        <div>

<%--   
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form.
--%>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<%--   
The Report Viewer Web Control
the ReportServerUrl and ReportPath configurations were copied from the BusinessIntelligence_Reporting project published on the SSRS server, TARGET_SERVER_URL and TARGET_REPORT_FOLDER
<ServerReport ReportServerUrl=TARGET_SERVER_URL ReportPath=TARGET_REPORT_FOLDER  />
--%>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Height="100%" Width="100%">
            <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://localhost/reportserver" ReportPath="/ProgettoReport1" />
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////////////////

run the project/solution, so to view the WebForm page with the report ...

get error message

/////////////////////////////////////

mozilla firefox
http://localhost:53119/Pages/ReportVendutoProdotti.aspx

webbrowser output error

```
ReportViewer1
Report Viewer Configuration Error

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. 
Add 
<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> 
to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, 
or add 
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> 
to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

The operation you are trying to run on "/ ProjectReport1" is not allowed for this type of item. (RsWrongItemType)
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

if I try to write the suggested configuration, I get another error,

SoluzReport1\WebSiteWebFormReport1\Web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> 
    </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
```

/////////////////////////////////////

run the project/solution, so to view the WebForm page with the report ... 
get error message

/////////////////////////////////////

mozilla firefox
http://localhost:53119/Pages/ReportVendutoProdotti.aspx

webbrowser output

```
HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting was found that does not apply in integrated managed pipeline mode.
Most likely causes:

  This application defines the configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.

Possible operations:

    Migrate the configuration to the system.webServer/handlers section. 
    You can do it manually or by using AppCmd ​​from the command line. 
    For example, run appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site" from the IIS Express installation directory. 
    Using AppCmd ​​to migrate your application allows you to work in integrated mode and continue working in classic mode and in previous versions of IIS.

    If you are sure you can ignore this error, you can disable it by setting system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to False.

    Alternatively, pass the application to a classic application pool. 
    For example, run appcmd set "Default Web Site/" /applicationPool:"Clr4ClassicAppPool" from the IIS Express installation directory. Do this only if you are unable to migrate your application.
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

if the problem is the couple  Visualstudio2017 and WebForm
I could try to use a page of a MVC project

otherwise I would be grateful if you can help me solve with the WebForms

///////////////////////////////////////////

PS my environment:

Windows10

visual studio 2017

ASP.NET WebForms

SSRS Reporting

"Visual Studio Development Server" to run the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message error

http://localhost:53119/Pages/ReportVendutoProdotti.aspx

HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting was found that does not apply in integrated managed pipeline mode.

solved by following this post

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/872364/HTTP-Error-Internal-Server-Error-in-Visual-Studio

Step 1

Open Visual Studio and click in the name of Website Project currently opened. 
Click on Property pane.

Step 2

Double click on Managed Pipeline Mode. This will toggle between Classic and Integrated Mode. You have to switch to Classic mode
Now hit the F5 button, here goes the output as usual.

http://localhost:53119/Pages/ReportVendutoProdotti.aspx

OK !!! now the report is displayed

SOLVED